# Give point to post author on unique post view

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using this package  `https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable` to record post view with this package

`https://github.com/ansezz/laravel-gamify`

so I will like to give author point when there post is viewed but the view must be unique in order to give point

example when a user view the author post give author point , but when that same user view the same post again don't give author point

```
public function mount(Post $post)
{
   $this->post = $post
   views($post)->cool down(24)->record();

 if(views($post)->count()> 1 ){
       $point = Point::find(2);
      $this->post->user->achievePoint($point);
   }
}
```

Comment: Are users viewing posts logged in?

Comment: yes they logged in before viewing the post